# Find the parameterization: The left half of the parabola $y=x^2+2x$

Tags: parametric, parameter-estimation, parametrization

Find the parameterization: The ***left*** half of $y=x^2+2x$

Here's what I did:

I set $x=t$, so that $y=t^2+2t$

Then the parameterization would be:
$$x=t$$ 
$$y=t^2+2t$$
$$t<0$$

Is that right?
 If it is, can the restriction be $t \le 0$ or does it have to be $t<0$?

Comment: It is 100% right, and the answer to your last question depends on your definition of "left half" - is that including the origin or not? Or does it include just the left half of the origin?

Comment: It is not completely right, as answered Piquito: the vertex is at (-1,3)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the left side of your parabola it means to the left of the axis of symmetry which is the line $x=-1$ so you can put $$t\le -1$$ instead of $t\le 0$.